# Pydantic: Why are field values referencing another model converted to dictionaries when using .dict?

Tags: python, pydantic

My problem is that when I iterate over a model instance using `.dict`, field values referencing other models are converted to dictionaries, e.g.:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Model(BaseModel):
    attr: str


class AnotherModel(BaseModel):
    attr: str
    model_attr: Model


model = AnotherModel(attr="test", model_attr=Model(attr="something"))

# field values are model objects
for field in model:
    print(field)

# field values are dictionaries
for key, val in model.dict().items():
    print((key, val))
```

Why is that and how can I change it?

Comment: This is not a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) yet because it is not complete and there is nothing to reproduce. (There is also irrelevant config stuff here, so it is not minimal.) Please edit your question and add the actual code you are executing along with the output you are seeing and the output you _expect_.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg thanks for replying and sorry for the initial fragments; actually my question concerns the `.dict` method. I supplied an example.

Comment: OK, I still don't understand what output exactly you mean and what you expected. When I run this code, the output of the `print` calls in the second loop is `('attr', 'test')` `('model_attr', {'attr': 'something'})`, which is exactly what I expected. And neither of those values is a _generator_. The `model_attr` value is a dictionary. Calling the [`dict`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/exporting_models/#modeldict) method dumps the entire instance as a dictionary and that happens recursively, i.e. field values that are models themselves are also converted to dictionaries. (see docs)

Comment: Again, if you show your _desired_ output or explain what it is you would like to achieve, maybe we can figure something out.

Comment: Sorry again, the generator thing was from my actual application and not this reduced example; what I'd like to know is: is there a way to prevent this recursive behavior of `.dict` so that the dictionary values are references to model instances, not dictionaries themselves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling the [`BaseModel.dict`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/exporting_models/#modeldict) method

> Sub-models will be recursively converted to dictionaries.

So this is expected behavior.

There was a [request made here](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/1518) to add an option for making it **non-recursive**, but it was denied.

Currently, the simplest solution is to just utilize the [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable) protocol [implemented by `BaseModel`](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.8/pydantic/main.py#L817) and simply cast it to a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict) or use the [`_iter`](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.8/pydantic/main.py#L823) method first for more fine-grained control (e.g. excluding unset fields or returning the field aliases):

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Foo(BaseModel):
    x: int


class Bar(BaseModel):
    y: float
    foo: Foo


bar = Bar(y=3.14, foo=Foo(x=0))
print(bar.dict())         # {'y': 3.14, 'foo': {'x': 0}}
print(dict(bar))          # {'y': 3.14, 'foo': Foo(x=0)}
print(dict(bar._iter()))  # {'y': 3.14, 'foo': Foo(x=0)}
```

---

Starting with Pydantic v2 you will probably use the [`model_dump`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/blog/pydantic-v2/#model-namespace-cleanup) instead of the `dict` method. And [the plan](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/blog/pydantic-v2/#improvements-to-dumpingserializationexport) seems to be to also allow dumping

> the field values of a model with no conversion, effectively `model.__dict__` [...].

So calling `bar.model_dump(mode="unchanged")` would be essentially what you asked for. But I am not sure if this is stable yet.

Comment: what about if you wanted to make foo: Foo optional? Would it look like Optional[Foo] ? (from typing import Optional)

Comment: @aero8991 This seems unrelated to the original question, but defining the model field as `foo: Optional[Foo]` is equivalent to `foo: Foo | None`, meaning the `foo` field would accept instances of `Foo` and also `None`. In Pydantic v1 declaring a field this way would also implicitly set the default for it to `None`, thus making it **not required**. In Pydantic v2 that is no longer the case and a field is always considered **required**, unless you explicitly define a default. But again, this has no bearing on the answer to the model dumping question.